# how to send to the output a script's test

Tags: github, github-actions

I have a bash script which generates an execution matrix I wanna use within another job.

the scripts executes correctly, but when it comes to redirect the output, the step fails:

```yaml
Run echo "tst=$(${PWD}/dev/i18n-scripts/generate-matrix.sh)\n" >> $GITHUB_GITHUB_OUTPUT
  
/__w/_temp/ce44932f-d406-437e-b87d-842822d14b51.sh: 1: cannot create : Directory nonexistent
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

here is the step:

```yaml
        steps:
            - name: checkout
              uses: actions/checkout@v3
            - name: make-it-executable
              run: chmod +x ${PWD}/dev/i18n-scripts/generate-matrix.sh
            - name: set-matrix
              run: echo "tst=$(${PWD}/dev/i18n-scripts/generate-matrix.sh)\n" >> $GITHUB_GITHUB_OUTPUT
```

If I remove `>> $GITHUB_GITHUB_OUTPUT` it executes correctly, without the expected output set, of course. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Typo: `$GITHUB_GITHUB_OUTPUT` should be `$GITHUB_OUTPUT`.

Comment: See https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using $GITHUB_OUTPUT instead of $GITHUB_GITHUB_OUTPUT:

```
Run echo "tst=$(${PWD}/dev/i18n-scripts/generate-matrix.sh)\n" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
```